# Diferença entre ListView e ListActivity

Tags: android

Estou com uma pequena dúvida, qual a diferença entre uma *ListActivity* e uma *ListView* ?

Answer (score 8):

Primeiro te aconselho a estudar a diferença entre `Activity` e `View`, pois são coisas absolutamente diferentes. Depois disso você vai perceber que `ListView` é um tipo de implementação de `View`, mais especificamente de `ViewGroup`, que permite exibir **views** em forma de lista.

Já `ListActivity` é uma `Activity` normal, mas que já tem mecanismos para facilitar o uso de listas como o `ListView`.

Acesse a documentação de [ListView](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) e [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) para mais detalhes.